# Function filter() failing with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following code (Using Apps Script and Google Sheets)
All columns on "searchColumns" are NOT NULL. I realize that the problem is due to other NULL columns on "dados" because the code runs fine when all columns have data.
Is there a way to overcome this issue? Some columns are in fact blank and I need them as they are...

Many thanks for any kind help.
Octavio

````
    function procurar(){
dados = [[1.0, LEROY MERLIN - PRODUTO BOLORES E SANYTOL, COMPRAS HIGIENIZAÇÃO, 8.08, Banco, , , , , Expense, , C, , FR443, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.51, 0.0, 6.57], [2.0, JARDIM GARVE - 3 SACOS SIRO ROYAL, COMPRAS JARDIM, 49.51, Banco, , , , , Expense, , C, , HT525, 2.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 46.71]]
  var searchInput = "LEROY"
  var searchWords = searchInput.split(/\s+/);
  var searchColumns = [1,2,3];
  var resultadosProcura = searchInput === "" ? [] : dados.filter(function(r){   //This line fails with: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'filter')"
  ...
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

After an hard work I found a solution. I am very new to this and teaching myself, so I bet most of the people here must must have thought my question was stupid. In fact, the problem was due not to NULL columns but to columns containing cells with wrong data, e.g. '5BBlaBla' value caused the problem but 'z5BBlaBla' works fine.
My apologies for taking your time.

Comment: Nice answer to your own problem. You learned something here, which will benefit other people when you share it. Keep up the good work. :)